# C++ Code do not return vector as expected and throws errors on conversion

Tags: c++, vector

I have written a block of Code.

What it does? It prints something, then ask the user to insert the name of his favorite author, and then add the inserted author into a vector.

In the two last lines of the code, respectively, the vector of the authors is assigned to a vector variable, but upon this line, it throws the following code:

```
error C2664: 'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>::basic_string(std::initializer_list<_Elem>,const std::allocator<char> &)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::vector<std::string,std::allocator<_Ty>>' to 'const std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> &'
```

It thus does not reach to the last line.

However, my problem is that, I want to return a vector of authors to which an author is added by the user. And this causes the problem, since prior to this, the code was working.

Here is the code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class SimpleClass
{
public: string AuthorName;
public: string AuthorLastWork;
        vector<string> AuthorNames;
public: int AuthorBirthYear;

private: string AuthorBestSelling;
private: int AuthorNumOfSoldWorks;

public:
    void SetAuthorName(string Name)
    {
        this->AuthorName = Name;
        string namesOfAuthors[2] {"Jack London", "Flaubert"};
        if (Name == namesOfAuthors[0])
        {
            this->setAuthorSoldWorks(2000000);
        }
        else if (Name == namesOfAuthors[1])
        {
            this->setAuthorSoldWorks(5000);
        }
    }

    int GetAuthorNumOfSoldWorks()
    {
        return this->AuthorNumOfSoldWorks;
    }


private :
    void setAuthorSoldWorks(int number)
    {
        this->AuthorNumOfSoldWorks = number;
    }
}; // END OF CLASS

class SecondClass : public SimpleClass
{
public:
    void AddAuthor(string name)
    {
        this->AuthorNames.push_back(name);
    }
     GetAuthors(string name)
    {
         return this->AuthorNames;
    }
};

int main()
{
    string AuthorNameByUser;

    SimpleClass SC;
    SecondClass SecondClass;
    SC.SetAuthorName("Jack London");

    cout << "This is our selected Author: " << SC.AuthorName << endl;

    cout << "Number of sold works: " << SC.GetAuthorNumOfSoldWorks() << " works." << endl;

    cout << endl;

    cout << "Please type the name of your favorite author: ";

    getline(cin, AuthorNameByUser);

    SecondClass.AddAuthor(AuthorNameByUser);

    vector<string> AuthorsCollection = SecondClass.GetAuthors();

    cout << "Thank for your particpiation. You have entered \"" << AuthorsCollection[0] << "\"" << endl;

}
```

Comment: You are missing the return value from your `GetAuthors` member function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `GetAuthors()` function has no return type.

You should add `std::vector<string> GetAuthors(){ ... }`.

Apart from that, you should not use `using namespace std;`, use more specific names than `SimpleClass`and `SecondClass` and don't mix public declarations with private ones, keep it in one block.